# FFMPEG action on events

Tags: linux, events, ffmpeg, automation, action

iam trying to make action on events in FFMPEG.

For example: ffmpeg -i http://domain/index.m3u8 -c copy -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 10 %Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.mp4

FFMPEG take live stream, cut by slices and create files. I want to run a script do_with_file.sh after every slice created, without ffmpeg pausing.

Is there any option in ffmpeg to make it?

Ofcource, i can take stdout from ffmpeg and looking for "segment" text:
ffmpeg ....mp4 | grep 'segment @' | do_with_file.sh

First of all, info line about "segment" showed in stdout, before file was created.
It is not working, if i want run ffmpeg in background.
And in my mind, it is not geek way :)

P.S. English is not my native language, sorry for mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask `ffmpeg` to tell you when a segment is finished recording:

```
-loglevel verbose
```

With this option you'll get the event you're looking for:

```
[segment @ 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f] segment:'filename.ext' count:N ended
```

But, if you're prefer a "geek" way, you may try `inotifywait`:

```
while segment=$(inotifywait --quiet --event close_write --format %w%f path/to/dir); do
  do_with_file $segment
done
```